# Understanding perl script {"branch"}

Tags: perl

```
# track the version for labeling
  print LBL $name."@@".$versions{$name}{"branch"}."/".$versions{$name}{"number"}."\n";
```

I don't understand the {"branch"} inside this print command. The result is as shown below:

```
/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/Engines@@/main/nz_mig/1
```

I don't see any words like "branch" or "number" here.

Thanks
Jim

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $versions{$name};`

Comment: I think the person asking the question should demonstrate at least some level of effort to actually understand the tool s/he is using.

Answer (score 1):

According to the question description, that `versions` supposes to be a hash, which includes at least the following keys and values

```
%versions = (
        '/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/Engines' => {
                branch => '/main/nz_mig',
                number => 1,
        },
);
```

And that `name` supposes to be a scalar value with the following value

```
$name = '/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/Engines';
```

So `$versions{$name}{"branch"}`, which equals `$versions{$name}->{branch}`,  will return the value associated with key `branch` in that hash reference associated with key `$name` in hash `%versions`.

To learn more about
[Perl data types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)
[Perl reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)